# How to avoid QTableView overflow?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

In my UI designer created form I sometimes face an overflow of the `QTable` view content. Any idea how I can avoid this?

[image]

The layout is like this:

```
QFrame
  QStackedWidget
     QWidget
        QTableView the view shown in the screenshot
     QWidget
     QWidget
  QFrame the buttons OK, Cancel
```

First my assumption was it is caused by the multi line content, but I face the same issue when I only use single line content (rows). I do not have the issue in other table views.

Has someone seen the same thing? I only have it with that particular situation, however there is also nothing special here.

Comment: Are you using a delegate for QTableView?

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: a) no delegate b) Not possible for me this time. If I was able to create that example in that particular case I would have solved the problem. I am more looking for someone who has faced the same situation and can provide 1-2 hints about his situation so I might identify a common denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I have found: If I set the `QTableView` scrollbar policy (vertical) to `ScrollBarAlwaysOn` the issue is gone.